# jquery bootstrap collapse not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have content in element `div class"collapse"` and 2 button:
1. first button for update data outside collapse elements 
2. second button for collapse element + update others data

my problem:
 1. if i open the page, element class `"collapse"` is hidden, when i click second button, collapse is show. then i want updating data in first button, immediately element `"collapse"` is hide. but why when i click first button, element "collapse" is show? even though, first button for updating data and hide element collapse. and second button  to show collapse...

https://jsfiddle.net/e6ny483c/

my page:

```
<div class="grid fluid">
    <div class="row ">
        <div id="containerTanggal" class="col-sm-4 " >
            Tanggal Monitoring:
            <div class="input-control text" style="width: 150px">
                <input type="text" name="tanggalMonitoring" id="tanggalMonitoring"/>
                <span id="image_button_tanggalMonitoring" class="btn-date"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="large primary btnLoadMonitoring" type="submit" id="btnLoadMonitoring">Lihat Monitoring</button>
    </div>

    <!--overview hari ini-->
    <div class="row">
        <!--gauge bensin-->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <section class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="top-stats-panel">
                        <div class="gauge-canvas">
                            <div class="widget-h">Penggunaan Bahan Bakar Hari Ini</div>
                            <canvas width=160 height=100 id="bahanbakarHariIni"></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="gauge-meta clearfix">
                            <li id="gauge-textfield" class="pull-left gauge-value"></li>
                            <li class="pull-right gauge-title">Liter</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <section class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="top-stats-panel">
                        <div class="daily-visit">
                            <div class="widget-h">Sampah Masuk Hari Ini</div>
                            <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                <div class="mini-stat-info" >
                                    <span id="tonaseHariIni"></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <ul class="chart-meta clearfix">
                                <li class="pull-left visit-chart-value" id="selisihTonase"></li>
                                <li class="pull-right visit-chart-title" id="persentaseSelisihTonase"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <section class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="top-stats-panel">
                        <div class="widget-h">Jenis Angkutan Sampah</div>
                        <div id="pie-chart-donut" class="pie-chart">
                            <div id="pie-donutContainer" style="width: 100%;height:150px; text-align: left;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <section class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="top-stats-panel">
                        <div class="widget-h">Kendaraan aktif hari ini</div>
                        <div >
                            <ol id="totalJenisKendaraanAktif" class="list-group">

                            </ol>
                            <div class="daily-sales-info" id="totalKendaraanAktif">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <!--tonase graph start-->
            <section class="panel">
                <header class="panel-heading">Tonase Lima TPS terbesar
                       <!-- <span class="tools pull-right">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
                        </span>-->
                </header>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="tonaseLimaHariTPS" class="main-chart">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--tonase graph end-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <section class="panel">
                <header class="panel-heading">
                    Total Tonase 5 Hari Terakhir
                </header>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="tonaseLimaHariTotal"></div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="next">Selanjutnya</button>


        <div class="collapse">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="panel">
                                        <header class="panel-heading">
                                                Total Tonase Satu Bulan
                                        </header>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div id="tonaseSatuBulanTotal"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </section>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="panel">
                                        <header class="panel-heading">
                                                Total Bahan Bakar Satu Bulan
                                        </header>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div id="bahanBakarSatuBulanTotal"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </section>
                </div>
            </div>

                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <section class="panel">
                                            <header class="panel-heading">
                                                    Rute Terakhir Seluruh Kendaraan
                                                        <!--  <span class="tools pull-right">
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
                                                             </span>-->
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                    <div class="adv-table">
                                                            <table class="display table table-bordered table-striped" id="ruteIndex">
                                                                    <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                            <th>Nomor Polisi</th>
                                                                            <th>Nama Supir</th>
                                                                            <th>Rute Asal</th>
                                                                            <th>Rute Tujuan</th>
                                                                            <th class="hidden-phone">Waktu Berangkat</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-phone">Waktu Target</th>
                                            <th>Lapor</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    </thead>
                                                                    <tbody id="tabelRute">
                                                                    </tbody>
                                                                    <tfoot>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                            <th>Nomor Polisi</th>
                                                                            <th>Nama Supir</th>
                                                                            <th>Rute Asal</th>
                                                                            <th>Rute Tujuan</th>
                                                                            <th class="hidden-phone">Waktu Berangkat</th>
                                            <th class="hidden-phone">Waktu Target</th>
                                            <th>Lapor</th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    </tfoot>
                                                            </table>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </section>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                    <section class="panel">
                                            <header class="panel-heading">
                                                    Peta Surabaya <strong>(KLIK NOPOL PADA TABEL DI ATAS UNTUK MELIHAT RUTE)</strong>
                                                            <!--<span class="tools pull-right">
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
                                                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="fa fa-times"></a>
                                                             </span>-->
                                            </header>
                                            <div class="panel-body" >
                                                    <h3 id="estimasiWaktu"></h3>
                                                    <div id="petaSurabaya" style="height: 500px;"></div>
                                            </div>
                                    </section>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                            <span class="mini-stat-icon pink"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                                            <div class="mini-stat-info">
                                                    <span id="detailNopol"></span>
                                                    Nomor Polisi Kendaraan
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                            <span class="mini-stat-icon green"><i class="fa fa-road"></i></span>
                                            <div class="mini-stat-info">
                                                    <span id="detailJarak"></span>
                                                    Estimasi Jarak Ditempuh
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                            <span class="mini-stat-icon tar"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i></span>
                                            <div class="mini-stat-info">
                                                    <span id="detailWaktuBerangkat"></span>
                                                    Estimasi Waktu Berangkat
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                            <span class="mini-stat-icon orange"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                                            <div class="mini-stat-info">
                                                    <span id="detailWaktuSampai"></span>
                                                    Estimasi Waktu Sampai
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    <div id="divDetailWaktuSampaiTPA" class="col-md-3 hidden">
                                    <div class="mini-stat clearfix">
                                            <span class="mini-stat-icon orange"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span>
                                            <div class="mini-stat-info">
                                                    <span id="detailWaktuSampaiTPA"></span>
                                                    Estimasi Waktu Sampai TPA
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").collapse('show');
    });
});

$(".btnLoadMonitoring").click(function(){
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
        tanggal = $("#tanggalMonitoring").val();
        console.log(tanggal);
        updateMonitoring(tanggal);
    });
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @vel, already on top..., i want collapse always hide every click first button. but when i first click on the first button, collapse is open and then second click, third click, and so on.... collapse is hide correctly..., i has a problem on first click

Comment: I got error in jsfiffle `VM70 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
    at `.

Answer (score 1):

this problem is solved....

i just added

```
$(".collapse").collapse({toggle:false});
```

like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".collapse").collapse({toggle:false});
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
            $(".collapse").collapse('show');
    });
});
```

thank you for responding to my question

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong....
for button...

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingDiv">Load Monitoring</button>
<div id="collapsingDiv" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit eos aut ea facere enim doloremque aliquam, ratione placeat, aspernatur at accusantium consequatur, itaque perferendis laboriosam architecto nam magni cupiditate error!
</div>
```

Comment: In case you want to show div collapse on load...
Add class "in" with collapse to the div#collapsingDiv,
No further javascript Jquery needed...
Only bootstrap - css And js is needed...

Comment: Okay ill soon when free copy yr fiddle  and make a working fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav__work/6rwxupb8/7/

SEE This Fiddle...
Its working..
Actually problem is not your code..
But you are using wrong js with wrong bootstrap..
I have used 3.3.7 version of bootstrap 
But u have used 4 version 
And some errros it was showing like popover js was missing..
I have worked with ...
Bootstrap 3 not 4 version till now
So I suggest u to change files or update popover js in ur html..
IT will work

Comment: you are using bootstrap-3 classes 
And u have placed file of bootstrap-4 
please check external resources..
Popover js is required in bootstrap-4 not bootstrap-3